# Imgur TagVote issue python

Tags: python, imgur

A beginner here, I am using the imgur python library to get tags related to an image. For this I am using the gallery_item_tags method as mentioned [here.](https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython)

However whenever i call the method it gives me an output as shown [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRBgi.png)

I have followed the authorization procedure using the needed client id and client secret and i can run all methods not involving TagVotes array. How can i get the required information from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a list of [TagVote instances](https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython/blob/master/imgurpython/imgur/models/tag_vote.py). You probably want the name, you can access it like this:

```
for tag in tags:
  print tag.name
```